# Структура для repost/share

Tags: mysql, sql

Делаю сайт с социальными элементами. Важная часть это "лента сообщений" от конкретного пользователя или от списка тех, на кого подписан. Хочется добавить еще возможность "репоста" или "шаринга". Чтобы в ленту новостей от друзей попадали и расшаренные ими сообщения.

Посоветуйте пожалуйста красивое и не слишком дорогое решение через один SQL-запрос.

За старт можно взять вот такую структуру: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85386/1

Comment: в приведённом примере и так один запрос. уточните, пожалуйста, что именно требуется.

Comment: В приведенном примере нет того, о чем я спрашиваю: репостов. Их надо добавить. Я ввел основу чтобы добрые люди не с нуля начинали.

Comment: репост, имхо, лучше делать копией исходного поста (а вдруг оригинал удалят или юзер удалится?) с указанием оригинала. т.е. достаточно одного доп. поля для ссылки на оригинал, в остальном будет полный дубль. ну и при выводе обращать внимание на это новое поле.

Comment: @artoodetoo, я думаю, вам быстрее ответят, если вы приведёте пример «некрасивого и дорогого» решения. ведь вникать в предметную область — значительно дольше, чем предложить более оптимальный *sql-запрос*. кстати, ещё лучше будет, если вы вставите fiddle прямо в вопрос: справа от кнопки *run sql* — выпадающий спиок, выберите  *markdown output* и вставьте полученный *markdown* в вопрос. только у них там «некрасивость» [есть](https://github.com/jakefeasel/sqlfiddle2/pull/23): между строкой *results* и самими результатми надо вставлять пустую строку.

Comment: @alexander barakin, спасибо за внимание.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, я такой вариант тоже рассматриваю, спасибо! С т.з. производительности наверное самый лучший. Тут есть свои заморочки, например как поступать, когда оригинал редактируется.

Comment: @artoodetoo, это как у вам удобно/угодно. Можно апдейтить body для репостов одним запросом, можно оставлять все как есть, типа репостили конкретное, а не "что-то что может быть в будущем"...

Comment: @ Yura Ivanov, другое осложнение это прикрепленные к сообщению файлы. В случае копирования сообщения надо копировать и записи о файлах. При редактировании оригинала надо  и эти штуки синхронизировать. Вариант "оставить как было" не годится, из соображений собственности - всё-таки хозяин тот, кто разместил оригинал. Если кто-то захочет *буквально* копировать сообщение, он сделает это сам — закопипастит, сохранит и загрузит заново файлы. Но при *расшаривании* мы всё-таки имеем в виду орингинал!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я применил вариант, когда создается новое сообщение со своим собственным текстом + ссылка на расшариваемое сообщение в доп. поле. Запрос можно увидеть здесь: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eface/1

Другие кандидаты, оказавшиеся за бортом:

- Простое копирование сообщения, предложенное @Yura Ivanov. Запрос на выборку был бы самым простым и быстрым, но из дополнительных соображений этот вариант не подошел. Минусы: неочевидность прав и сложность синхронизации при изменении оригинала.
- Две таблицы: лента пользователя + сообщения. Где в ленте пользователя могут быть ссылки как на собственные сообщения, так и на сообщения кого угодно.